# Is there a way to create a function to load all data files in directory and then output their file name and content?-Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, glob

Is there a way to create a function to load all data files in directory and then output their file name and content?

**Input:** Get all files in a given directory of mine (wow.txt, testting.txt, etc.)

**Process:** I want to run all the files through a function

**Output:** I want the output to be the total number of files processed and all the files names and their respective content below it.

For example:

```
Total Number of Documents: 6

/home/file/wow.txt

"all of its content"

/home/file/www.txt

"all of its content"
```

Here is my code:

```
#Import Functions  
import glob
# get all the .txt files
files=glob.glob("*.txt")  

#Load Data Function
def load_data(files):
    """
    Input  : path to all .txt files
    Purpose: loading all text file
    Output : list of documents along with their respective content 

    """

    documents_list=[]
    content=[]

    for file in files:
        with open(file,"rt",encoding="latin-1") as fin:
            print(file)
            for line in fin.readlines():
                text = line.strip()
                documents_list.append(text)
        print("Total Number of Documents:",len(documents_list))
        content.append( text[0:min(len(text),100)])
    return documents_list,content

#Output
load_data(files)
```

Here is my output:

[image]

[image]

1. As you can see in the first part of the output, it's showing each file and random number. Instead it should just have the total number of documents (which is 5)
2. It shows the content of all the files but it doesn't separate them by file. As you can see by the red line, that shows the end of the first file and below the red line is the start of another.

Any suggestions?

Comment: (1) it is not random number - it is number of all lines in your files. You put lines in `documents_list`, not full document.

Comment: The only reason you see the contents printed is because IPython echoes the return value of the `load_data()` function. If that's not the right output, you need to handle the printing in your own code.

Comment: @furas: no, it's a number read from the first file.

Comment: `len(documents_list)` appears to be the total lines in ALL documents, not the total number of documents.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right - first number is from file. I was thinking of line with text ""Total Number of Documents"

Answer (score 0):

```py
def print_files_in_directory(directory):
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(f)]
    print(f'Total Number of Documents: {len(files)}')
    for f in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, f)
        print(file_path)
        print('\n')
        with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
            print(fp.read())
```

If you want it to include files in subdirectories, you'll either have to manually recurse those subdirectories yourself or use os.walk()